# Cannot connect to external Mongodb IP through Docker

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

I uses docker to deploy my Spring boot Netflix microservice multi-projects.

I do not have any problem to docker run my eureka and config projects.

However when I communicate another project to eureka, system throws the following error

```
 monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket.
```

I understand that Spring boot by default connect to localhost if it cannot communicate to the Mongodb through uri set to spring.data.mongodb.uri of application.xml of config repository.

I am 100% sure that this spring.data.mongodb.uri points to the correct url. However, when I run /env of Spring actuator page, I cannot see spring.data.mongodb.uri.

If I deploy eureka, config and the the project without docker, system run well.

Can anyone advise why the behavior in docker and non-docker environments are different?

Answer (score 0):

When running in docker containers (if you run everything in docker containers), there is a default network to which all containers connect to. For example, default network's subnet is 172.16.1.0/28. You can inspect which ip address is used by each container using:

```
docker inspect {name-or-id-of-container}
```

This means that, by default, port 27017 is not available in localhost.

UPDATE:
I've created a sample project involving Eureka Server, Config Server and Application reading spring.data.mongodb.uri property and printing to standard output.

https://github.com/bkuzmic/spring-cloud-docker-sample

Comment: But I connect mongodb to a url where the mongodb is not setup with docker

Comment: Your application, if runs in docker container, can't see mongodb through localhost. Try setting the ip address of mongodb in your project configuration to be the current ip address of your machine (the one on the eth0 or eth1 network devices)

Comment: To app running in docker, localhost means container itself, not your machine.

Comment: Can you please provide more details of project setup? Do you use bootstrap.properties to connect to config server?

Comment: bootstrap.yml. For your information, I am able to connect using non-docker environment. I face problem only in docker environment.

Comment: How do you start docker containers? Can you provide the steps so I can try to reproduce it?